# How do I attack other FOB's

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

The servers are up
I have already been infiltrated 
but the game has given no explanation on how I'd infiltrate another players FOB's

I am playing on Xbox One with latest updates and completly logged into MGS servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have your iDroid open from inside the helicopter, check in the third tab from the left, there should be a section for 'FOB Missions'.  Once you select that menu, it should load a list of random players that you can invade.  You'll be able to invade more players after you get a certain amount of Heroism.  Additional context in the spoiler below

> These are players with nuclear weapons

The other tabs on this menu should indicate who you've been attacked by, who you can retaliate against, and a tab for supporting other players.

This menu choice will not appear while you're on the ground.